# "Image size too large" error when saving quiver plot in python with clipping off

Tags: python, matplotlib, bounding-box, clipping, savefig

When I run the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.quiver(np.zeros(5), np.arange(5), np.ones(5), np.ones(5))
plt.savefig('test', bbox_inches = 'tight')
```

Things save fine.

But when I turn clipping off on the quiver plot...

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.quiver(np.zeros(5), np.arange(5), np.ones(5), np.ones(5), clip_on = False)
plt.savefig('test', bbox_inches = 'tight')
```

I get the following error:
ValueError: Image size of 684x260469 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.

What's going on here?

Comment: I get the error regardless of whether I use `bbox_inches` or not... Probably relevant commentary [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_clip_on.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_clip_on).

Comment: Weird, I only get the error if I use bbox_inches. I'm using Spyder with interactive plotting turned on...

Comment: Also using Spyder... just a simple `plt.show()` fails, as does `plt.savefig`.